# Working with different branches

Tags: git

I started using version control system recently and the only thing that boggles my mind is how to work with different branches. Lets say I named them **stable** and **experimental**. When I decide to switch from stable to experimental, is it okay to pull it from my repository into the same folder in which I had stable branch and vice versa or I should keep different branches on my computer in separate folders? Does it make any difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git works in the same folder for all branches in your project. All work from all branches is stored safely in the `.git` folder at the top of your project. When you switch branches, git actually deletes the files in that main project folder, then recreates the files in the branch you're switching to in their place.

Your commits are essentially snapshots of that one folder, and jumping around between branches, or back through time on any one particular branch just replaces the contents of the working folder - i.e. the main folder of your project - with the snapshot at that particular place in the tree of commits.

Answer (score 2):

It is fine. Before switching branches, commit your changes. When you switch back to the branch, your changes will be re-applied. You only need one folder for this, you almost never need to use to use two folders with git.